# Get URL of request from android app

Tags: android

I have a android apk file which is created using phonegap, This apk using the WPF service to communicate with database.

my question is that, does we have any tool which show me which URL is requested when i made any request from android app.

Comment: you have to request specific URL.. so shouldnt you know which URL did you request? where do you need such information? in app? on server?

Comment: No i don't know the URL becuase this apk is not made by me, i just made the WPF service but i want to know when any button is clicked by android app which URL is requested, i want to know that in the form of alert or log

Comment: your server should have such logs available. For example, my apache's access log looks like that:192.168.100.7 - - [15/Apr/2014:16:59:57 +0200] "POST /x.php HTTP/1.1" 200 160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"
192.168.100.7 - - [15/Apr/2014:16:59:57 +0200] "GET /y.php?pagenum=1&pagesize=20 HTTP/1.1" 200 350 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36"